# Querying same account_id, same status but not the current_user SQL RAILS

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, scope

I got this code of scope:

```
scope :all_except, ->(user) { where(status: ACTIVE, account_id: user).where.not(id: user) }
```

and this:

```
scope :all_except, ->(user) { where("status = ? AND account_id = ? AND NOT id = ?", ACTIVE, user, user)
```

I want to only display all the users with active status, same account_id and without the current user

But current user always appear in my collection

here's my code on view:

```
= f.collection_select :send_to_id, User.all_except(current_user.account_id), :id, :first_and_last_name, { include_blank: 'Select' }, { class: 'form-control' }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this as scope

```
scope :all_except, ->(user) { where("status = ? AND account_id = ? AND NOT id = ?", ACTIVE, user.account_id, user.id)
```

in view call this

```
= f.collection_select :send_to_id, User.all_except(current_user), :id, :first_and_last_name, { include_blank: 'Select' }, { class: 'form-control' }
```

Comment: undefined method `id' for 2:Fixnum

Comment: What is current_user.? It is supposed to be user object

Comment: If you are passing the id, then the argument should be named `user_id`. Corrected the answer

Comment: @YuryLebedev  sorry but the scope exists in User model and the we are passing current_user. how can foreign_key of user_id exists in users table.? shouldnt it be id.?

Comment: @Athar i did not changed the sql query, i just changed the scope argument

Comment: sorry my bad @YuryLebedev.

Comment: @YuryLebedev, based on my original scope, is just like the same with yours. You only modified the object user to user_id

Comment: actually you just changed the params passing to `all_except` scope. previously you are passing current_user object to the scope and matching id with object which was wrong. now you updated the query to send account_id which eventually solves your issue i think.

Comment: yep, as @Athar already wrote, your scope was not working, because in the db you compared the id with the string representation of the user object

Comment: I update my collection to current_user.account_id. But it gives me the same issue. Current User displayed also on my collection

Comment: @BartSabayton i have updated both collection where from im calling and the scope. please try that. it should work now

Comment: @BartSabayton can you add the output of this command to your question? 
`User.all_except(current_user.account_id).to_sql`

Comment: @YuryLebedev, here: SELECT `db_name`.`users`.* FROM `db_name`.`users` WHERE `db_name`.`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND (status = 'active' AND account_id = 2 AND NOT id = 1001)  ORDER BY created_at ASC

Comment: Yes! Finally, I got this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work (i would actually split a scope in two):

```
scope :with_account, -> (user_id) { where(account_id: user_id) }
scope :active, -> { where(status: ACTIVE) }
scope :all_except, -> (user_id) { where.not(id: user_id) }

User.active.with_account(current_user.account_id)
  .all_except(current_user.account_id)
```

Comment: undefined method `id' for 2:Fixnum

Comment: there's no error, but, current user appeared in my collection.

Comment: = f.collection_select :send_to_id, User.all_except(current_user.account_id), :id, :first_and_last_name, { include_blank: 'Select' }, { class: 'form-control' }

Comment: @BartSabayton i just realized: which `account_id` has your user? Maybe you should try this?
`User.all_except(current_user.id)`